# How make emacs console mode inherit shell colors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, emacs

I just upgraded my Ubuntu laptop from 12.04 to 12.10.

In 12.04, running `emacs -nw` opened `emacs` in terminal mode using the terminal color scheme (background, foreground, ..., especially it keeped my transparent terminal background).

Now in 12.10, running the same command results in emacs opened in the terminal with an other color scheme (with a gray background). How can I tell emacs to keep my terminal color scheme ?

Comment: http://batsov.com/articles/2012/02/19/color-theming-in-emacs-reloaded/

Comment: thanks for the link, but I don't want to have to deal with custom color theme edition but just indicate to emacs to re-use my gnome terminal colors

Comment: @ManuelSelva, do you have custom colors defined in your .emacs for when you are not running with -nw ?  if so, you could ignore them if you change your .emacs to check the variable `window-system is bound with a non-ni and conditionally skip them under that condition.  (in ubuntu i would expect this value to be bound to "X" for X-window system.  at the very worst, you should be able to use "emacs -q" which will ignore your .emacs altogether, but should give you the terminal colors you want with all default behavior.

Comment: @john.k.doe No I don't have any custom colors defined in my .emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/774691/john-k-doe's comment, I finally get the reason why my `emacs -nw` appeared like that.

I edited the font size (for the default face) in an `emacs` window (launched without the `-nw` option) and then saved this new setting using the menu entry `Options -> Save Options`. This action modified my `~/.xemacs/custom.el` file loaded by default in my `~/.emacs` file. The modification included background and foreground properties for the default face with the value used in "Window" mode.

To solve the issue, I just removed this custom entry from the `custom.el` file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is a sensible answer to this. After all, a gnome terminal colour theme lists three "colours": (1) Text, (2) Background (3) Bold.

The way Emacs works is that every bit of text is given a "face". A colour theme is a mapping of faces to colours. There are more than three faces...

Comment: My gnome terminal allows me to define more than three colors. In my previous configuration (Ubuntu 12.04) changing these colors changed emacs colors. For example one of these color was used by emacs to highlight keywords in C mode, changing the color in terminal preferences changed emacs higlighting.